# How to implement dragging in LWUIT?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-container

My LWUIT application has 3 Forms:

1) FormA
2) FormB
3) FormC

The current form  being displayed on the screen is FormB.

Case 1:

If the user swipes his finger LEFT on his touch screen phone, I want LWUIT to capture that 
event and display FormC

Case2:

If the user swipes his finger RIGHT on his touch screen phone, I want LWUIT to capture that 
event and display FormA

How do I do this? I think it has to do something with drag event but not sure how to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
just need to override pointerDragged method in form and get/cal its X,Y positions and display another form. 


new Form()
{

protected void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
if(x,y....)
{
form3.show();

}else
{
from1.show();
}
super.pointerDragged(x,y);

}

};

here x,y can be calculated based on screen resolutions and components u have added to it.
```

Comment: i implemented the pointerPressed() and the pointerReleased() method , calculated the difference between the co ordinates and then took a decision to show a particular form...

Comment: Hey can you please tell me how to frame the if condition here? Its not working for me.

There is just one x,y here ..how do i determine the points where the drag has started and the points where the drag has ended?

I wish to calculate the difference between these two points and then  take a decision as to show the form on the left or form on the right

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tabs component with 3 Containers, it supports Swipe. You can set the Tabs themselves to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking 3 forms use 3 containers under 1 form and setScrollableX(true) and add all components in appropriate containers.

Comment: ok then have you tried with PointerPressed / Pointerdragged method.? Override those methods and get X, Y pos (any) after firing event just call other form.show()

Comment: ok...do i need to add any particular eventlistener on my form? All i need is a pointer dragged event and the direction in which it is dragged. Then i can use FORMNAME.show(). can you tell me how to do that?